# Kenwood TH-D74 VOX on D-Star

Tags: ht, kenwood, d-star, kenwood-th-d74

TH-74D Why doesn't regular Vox work on D-Star?  It only works if "Transmit when Busy" is turned on. Bad for interruptions.

Answer (score 2):

OK after a couple of weeks I just stumbled onto the answer!  Basic Vox only works if you have squelch turned on to at least a minimum setting.